# Коннект через фтп под рутом

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

Как можно сконнектиться к серверу по фтп сразу под рутом?

Comment: Очевидно, использовать логин/пароль пользователя, обладающего рутовыми правами на FTP (надеюсь, на вашем FTP такого нет).

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от настроек. В большинстве случаев в linux по умолчанию root может коннектиться только через sftp по ключу. В CentOS ключи должны лежать в `root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, один на строку. В ubuntu, полагаю, место хранения аналогичное.

Answer (score 0):

Соединится используя логин/пароль root пользователя. Ровно то же что и с обычным пользователем, только логин/пароль для root.

Comment: А как задать пароль для рута?

Comment: @quaresma89 в смысле? Вот допустим у вас два поля ввода в одном(там где нужно вводить login ) вы вводите root или admin (или другое имя пользователя с root привелегиями), а в поле где вводите пароль, вводите соответствующий этому пользователю пароль.

Comment: Не получается,ввожу в поле логина root и пишут access denied

Comment: Мне нужно по фтп сконнектится под рутом,чтобы иметь все права на запись и чтение файлов и не играться задавать права на папку юзеру

Comment: @quaresma89 а пароль вводили?

Comment: Да конечно,даже в ssh открыл возможность заходить по рутом,всеравно ничего

Comment: @quaresma89 а какой клиент испольуете для ftp или через терминал?

Comment: WinSCP ну и PUTTY для ssh коннекта

Comment: @quaresma89 ну, а Вы уверены что Вам доступен root аккаунт, убедитесь в правильности ввода пароля, выполните переконфигурацию пакета ftp на сервере.

Comment: спасибо буду пробовать

Comment: Нашел.В файле /etc/ftpusers были определены все юзеры которым запрещен доступ через фтп,в списке и root был.Закомментировал,теперь конекчусь без проблем.